# How to start learning to develop an http scraping tool

Tags: .net, http, web, web-scraping

Is there some good tutorial or sample to learn about http web scraping? How to start developing a tool that can search on some web sites  and download specific information so I can collect it automatically and then analyse?? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tool commonly recommended for this is the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). It will take malformed HTML and massage it into XHTML and then a traversable DOM, so is very useful for the code you find in the wild, as opposed to approaches like RegEx, which are destined to break.

There are some examples and the API documentation here:

http://html-agility-pack.net/api

Some useful links:

- [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)
- [Parsing HTML Documents with the Html Agility Pack](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx)
- [Crawling a web sites with HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.beletsky.net/2010/09/crawling-web-sites-with-htmlagilitypack.html)
- [Getting Started With HTML Agility Pack](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/)